# Horror manga with umbrella woman

Tags: story-identification, manga, horror

I've already asked to find a different manga a while ago so pardon if this may be excessive.
I recall a manga where the main character is walking home to his apartment in a rainy day or night, and spots what I believe is a woman holding an umbrella, take that with a grain of salt since I don't remember much. Supposedly a myth where you shouldn't reply to said woman or look at said woman, I don't remember which one exactly, or else something bad would happen.
I remember something relating to garbage bags, possibly main character taking out trash or something similar. I believe after a few questions he ends up replying and that starts the story I guess? All of this should be taken with a bucket of salt since I don't remember much of it. When I search stuff similar to what I described I keep getting some other stuff so last resort is here ahah.

Comment: No worries with multiple queries. But do you know if this is a story in an anthology? A one-off? Part of a larger series? The framework is that of a few traditional *yokai* that you shouldn't address.

Comment: And did you stop reading after he addressed her, or do you know what happened?

Comment: One of these? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kasa-obake

Comment: I don't remember anything after that so I think that was the first chapter that would be the introduction or so. It's based off of a myth/yokai type stuff. I don't remember if it's fully horror or if it's a light hearted manga but that's mainly all I know. it's a normal manga; not an anthology or anything.

Comment: I don't recall there being any monster creatures, except for a a woman, so nothing like that I guess?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuchisake-onna ? That's the closest I'm aware of, not that I'm knowledgeable about youkai or modern urban legends. Or Mary-san, but that's a phone call.